# How to create a symbolic link across git branches?

Tags: git, branch, symlink

I am working on [the SO Ruby Chat rules repo](https://github.com/wconrad/so_ruby_chat). The `RULES.md` in master *should* be the same as `rules.md` on the gh-pages branch; however, it does not reflect changes of the latter.

I know that a symbolic link in Directory B simply points to a file in Directory A. I want to apply the same logic across branches in git.

Again, since the gh-pages branch is the main focus, I would like a symlink in master that points to `gh-pages/rules.md`. I have done some research and cannot find anything for this exact issue.

Comment: I've fixed the duplication that this question wishes to address, but in a different way.  The redundant copy of the rules, RULES.md in the master branch has been removed.  The question is still valid, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario you are trying to implement is not possible(sym link).

Please check the following things if you are worked or not.

1. Modified the rules.md file in master/any other branch.
2. Check the status using `git status`
3. Add rules.md file using `git add rules.md`
4. Commit your changes in git using `git commit -m "message against the changes"`
5. Once this is done you want your changes to be reflect in other branches also.
6. Move to your branch using `git checkout branchname`
7. And now merge the changes that you did in master.
8. For merging use `git merge branch name`

If there are no conflicts then it should merge smoothly. All your changes present in master branch reflects here.

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer. Your method results in more commits than I would like, but your first sentence is the real answer. I appreciate your advice. Do you know if a repo with a gh-pages branch can survive with the master branch removed? Where gh-pages becomes the new master?

Comment: Yes, one and only `gh-pages` branch is a possibility. That is what I've done for my [blog](https://github.com/embs/blog/branches). It can be accomplished through GitHub web interface ─ all you need to do is check `gh-pages` branch as the primary one and then remove the `master` branch.